# Excel VBA hard crash on ModifyAppliesToRange with no error message

Tags: excel, vba, crash

I'm getting a strange problem in Excel and VBA.

I'm calling `ModifyAppliesToRange` on various `FormatCondition`, along with quite a lot of other `FormatCondition` related stuff.

It works fine for a while (about 2-300 calls) and then for no reason I can see my Excel (and the VBA development environment) will shut down with no error from either my error handler or excel, no notification, nothing except a 'pause' where nothing happens until it crashes. This happens whether I'm running it normally or with a breakpoint and Step.

Depending on the exact contents of the WorkSheet's `FormatConditions` the exact number of times it works seems to vary. But if the starting condition is the same then the point of failure is the same (i.e. it fails on the same `FormatCondition`). Code failing is:

`myCF.ModifyAppliesToRange Union(range1, range2)`

where `myCF As FormatCondition`

I tried

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Union(range1, range2)
myCF.ModifyAppliesToRange rng
```

I checked: `myCF`, `range1`, `range2` and `rng` are all valid as far as I can tell, and show valid `.Address` strings (for the ranges). For example, it will fail on `range1.Address`=`"$DO$9:$GN$39,$BD$8:$BD$39"`, `range2.Address`=`"$CI$9:$DN$39"`, and the resulting `rng.Address`=`"$BD$8:$BD$39,$CI$9:$GN$39"`

So I tried

```
Set rng = Union(Range(CFFrom.AppliesTo.Address), Range(CFTo.AppliesTo.Address))
```

Same problem.

On occasion (under different start conditions) it will get past the above `ModifyAppliesToRange` but the moment I look at `myCF.AppliesTo.Address` the same crash happens - whether hovering a mouse over it, or showing it in Watches, or displaying it in Immediate. Yet `rng.Address` gives no such problem.

Yet it also seems to work just fine for 2-300 times.

I suspect a memory problem (but Excel is not using much memory or CPU, there's plenty of empty memory on the computer, I've used Option Explicit, and so on) or a hard limit or bug in Excel

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?
Any ideas as to how I can find out what is shutting down Excel?

NOTE: To give the exact way to reproduce it I'd have to post my entire spreadsheet and code, which I'm reluctant to do. Still I might be able to send one-on-one if need be.

Comment: Not a solution here, but fwiw I also just ran into this, using Excel 2010.  Sometimes my code seemed to run fine but after opening the saved result Excel tells some conditional formatting was corrupt and removes it -- I suspect that's identical to your formatting.AppliesTo.Address issue.  I'd classify it as the so manyth Excel bug tbh.

Comment: also: I first thought it was because my ranges were unions of areas as well, so I redesigned the format ranges to plain 1-area ranges and this thing still happens.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this problem as well.  It does seem to be an Excel bug to be honest.

However, according to [this Technet forum post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1a4f1f74-0d64-40aa-aeaf-4f5f45af38b4/excel-2007-problem-with-modifyappliestorange-function-for-conditional-formatting?forum=excel), it seems that Excel changes the format conditions collection on the fly when updating conditions.  Seeing as that might lead to nasty bugs when processing all conditions in a loop (like I did), I first rewrote my code so that it first collects all conditions to process in a Collection, and then loops over those.  That still gave me Excel crashes; possibly the condition objects themselves also get updated (created/destroyed) behind the scenes mid-way, causing stale pointers to deleted VBA objects?

Not trusting Excel to keep the order identical either, I then rewrote my code to keep looping over all conditions, finding the first to update and just restarting the loop, until not a single condition was left unprocessed.  So basically like:

```
Dim stillBusy As Boolean
Do
    stillBusy = False
    Dim nextCondition As FormatCondition
    For Each nextCondition In myRange.FormatConditions
      Dim newAreas As Range
      Set newAreas = ResizeAreas(nextCondition.AppliesTo, myRange.Rows.Count)
      If Not AreasEqual(nextCondition.AppliesTo, newAreas) Then
        Call nextCondition.ModifyAppliesToRange(newAreas)
        stillBusy = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
Loop While stillBusy
```

And while this is super inefficient, it... miraculously works?! (for now).  Hopefully it also works for anyone else?

Btw: `ResizeAreas` and `AreasEqual` are some of my own helper functions; ResizeAreas transforms e.g. `[A1:A3,C1:D3]` to `[A1:A6,C1:D6]`, and AreasEqual looks if the given two ranges are composed of the exact same cells (`[A1:A2,B1:B2]` and `[A1:B2]` = True)

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful!  Key to yours working is the "Dim nextConditoin..." where you have it.  If it is placed outside the loop, Excel can crash.  In my implementation, I compared .AppliesTo.Address to the desired range, instead of your method to use Areas functions.